# Add a worker node to a master node via ssh

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, nodes

I have two servers connected to the internet.
Both can reach each other via ssh.

One should be the kubernetes master node and one i'd like to be a worker node.

How can i connect the worker node only via ssh.
I do not want to open other ports than 22.

Edit:
@Community Don't know how to limit it more? What is not specific enough?
My problem is:
i have a vm which should run as a kubernetes worker node. The only port i want to open on that vm is port 22 (ssh). How can i connect such a box as a worker node to a kubernetes cluster, working on another machine where also only port 22 is open.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. SSH into your VM,
2. Join the VM as a worker node via join command(*should be entered in master node*) via:

   `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`

> considering you've installed prerequisites.

3. Now that you've joined node, in Master/control plane, check if it is added as node via the command:

   `kubectl get nodes`

P.S Also note that there should be default ports which should be open between Master node and worker node:

Read more: [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ports-and-protocols/).

Comment: kumar Is the communication between worker node and master node then handled over ssh? Or do they need some ports to be opened?

Comment: @CloudCuckooHome, Yes, both need to communicate via various ports listed here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ports-and-protocols/

Comment: And my question was about using ssh instead of opening all those ports to the public internet...